# Wordpress Custome Meta Box for Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7, meta-boxes

I have created a meta box to store short code for contact form 7. The meta box works fine, the issue is when I use do_shortcode to ouput the shortcode I get "404 Not Found" displayed in the shotcode. Example [contact-form-7 "404 NOT FOUND"]. I know the original shortcode works, do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="59" title="Contact Form"]'); works fine. My following code does not work, please help.

```
<?php
    if(get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'shortcode_input', true )) {
        $contact_shortcode = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_input', TRUE );
    }
    echo do_shortcode($contact_shortcode);

?>
```

Comment: Looks like you have typo.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have typo in your code, your IF condition is never true due to `get_the_id()`, it should be `get_the_ID()`

```
  <?php
    if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_input', true )) {
        $contact_shortcode = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_input', TRUE );
    }
    echo do_shortcode($contact_shortcode);

?>
```

Also I suggest moving echo statement within the IF condition so you echo shortcode only when you have the shortcode i.e.

```
     <?php
            if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_input', true )) {
                $contact_shortcode = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_input', TRUE );
                echo do_shortcode($contact_shortcode);
            }


        ?>
```

Comment: No, that's not it. The outcome is the same. I still get [contact-form-7 "404 NOT FOUND"] as the output. The if statement works as is. The variable is assigned and if I just output the variable I get the correct shortcode that was stored. the issue comes when I use that variable in do_shortcode().

Comment: can you var_dump the value of your post meta and see if you have value being saved or not? $cf7_code = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_input', true ); then var_dump($cf7_code); and see if you have value assigned and what is it?